# sql server agent proxy account

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, proxy

I am trying to use proxy account for non sysadmin to grant them exec permission on xp_cmdshell.
What I did is:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE CREDENTIAL [proxyaccount] WITH IDENTITY = N'domain\user', SECRET = N'password'
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE CREDENTIAL [proxyaccount] WITH IDENTITY = N'domain\user', SECRET = N'password'
GO

USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy @proxy_name=N'myproxy',@credential_name=N'proxyaccount',
                @enabled=1
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'myproxy', @subsystem_id=2  
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'myproxy', @subsystem_id=3
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'myproxy', @subsystem_id=11
GO
```

But still when the user tries to do

```
xp_cmdshell 'dir c:'
```

It gives the following error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

Anyone knows what else should i be doing? The login only has connect permission to the server.

thanks in advance

Comment: why would you want to allow non-admins to execute xp_cmdshell?

Comment: its part of an agent job owned by the user. and for security reasons i don't want to change job owner to sa

Answer (score 0):

You shoud simply use

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'domain\user', 'password';
```

instead. I am not 100% sure but I think xp_cmdshell explicitly looks for a proxy account called ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## - this is what the stired procedure above will create for you.